# Gitlab-ci для java-проекта

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

помогите сконфигурировать gitlab-ci файл для java-проекта без Maven, Gradle и т.д. Вот мой файл, сделанный по подобию найденного в интернете:

```
image: java:latest

stages:
    - build

build:
    stage: build
    script: 
        - '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\javac" StockServer.java'
    artifacts:
        paths:
         - StockServer.*
```

Но т.к. проект собирается на удалённой машине, то файл StockServer ему найти не удаётся (в примере HelloWorld лежал в той же папке). Как правильно прописать путь к файлу, который лежит в папке runner'a? И будет ли это компиляцией всего проекта (StockServer содержит main()) или только отдельного класса?

Answer (score 1):

Мой ответ будет не совсем на поставленный вопрос, но решением своим я поделюсь - я добавил gradle в свой проект, а уже с его помощью и таким .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: java:8-jdk

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - main_project/build/libs/*.jar
```

я реализовал сборку jar файла на gitlab. Мне кажется, что такой вариант лучше, т.к. мне подсказали, что собирать проект "руками" не комильфо.